# Office Online Server: Excel - We couldn't find the file you wanted. It's possible the file was renamed, moved or deleted

Tags: 2016, office-online-server

Running SharePoint 2016, recently changed security configurations to set up Kerberos, remove older SSL and TLS settings.

After making the changes and restarting we started getting these errors on Office Online Server files:

Excel: We couldn't find the file you wanted.
It's possible the file was renamed, moved or deleted.

Word Document : "Sorry, there was a problem and we can't open this document. If this happens again, try opening the document in Microsoft Word."

I've rolled back the authentication changes, so it's back to using NTLM, but it's still giving these errors.

I've removed and re-added the bindings.

How can I get the OOS to show the files again?

Environment: 1 WFE, 1 App, 1 OOS server

communicating over HTTPS, using external-https WOPIzone

Answer (score 0):

After looking in the logs on the OOS server I found that there was a problem with the communication algorithm.  I put in the registry keys to enable strong encryption on the OOS server, restarted and it worked.